# Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables

Tags: r

I am trying to apply the codes to my data in this link 
https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html#sentiment-analysis-with-inner-join

The code in the book is

```
nrc_joy <- get_sentiments("nrc") %>% 
  filter(sentiment == "joy")
tidy_books %>%
  filter(book == "Emma") %>%
  inner_join(nrc_joy) %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE)
```

I wrote it like the following (excluded "filter" because I have just filenames and words columns in my data)

```
nrc_joy <- get_sentiments("nrc") %>% 
  filter(sentiment == "joy")
```

`abc %>%
      inner_join(nrc_joy ) %>% 
      count(word, sort = TRUE)`

I get this error:

> Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables

Any ideas how to deal with it?

Comment: you don't have the same column names for the two tables, so there is no "natural" join to guess

Comment: I think this error comes from something different. Maybe, I should include something like as in the link https://github.com/duttashi/text-analysis/issues/4

Comment: Introduce a new column to act as an ID in both datasets and join using that(I think).

Comment: In the Github issue, the problem is that they didn't have matching columns / column names between the two data frames. If you have matching columns in both data frames, e.g. an ID, a join function can guess that that's the column to join by. If not, you need to supply `by`, such as `by = c("id1" = "id2")`. The docs for `inner_join` explain this pretty well

Answer (score 0):

After running into a similar issue this is what I found.

The complete code from the website is:

```
library(janeaustenr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

tidy_books <- austen_books() %>%
              group_by(book) %>%
              mutate(linenumber = row_number(),
              chapter = cumsum(str_detect(text, 
                                          regex("^chapter [\\divxlc]", 
                                          ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>%
              ungroup() %>%
              unnest_tokens(word, text)

nrc_joy <- get_sentiments("nrc") %>% 
filter(sentiment == "joy")
```

The 'abc' dataset is unspecified in the question; however, it is easy to make up a substitute dataset using a 'differentColumnNameForWord'.

```
library(tidytext)
abc <- data.frame(differentColumnNameForWord = stop_words$word, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The way to find which column name the words are stored in the data frame is to use the 'names' function.

```
> names(abc)
[1] "DifferentColumnNameForWord"
```

Once the name of the column is identified the code would need to be modified as follows:

```
abc %>% inner_join(nrc_joy, by = c("DifferentColumnNameForWord" = "word")) %>% 
        count(DifferentColumnNameForWord, sort = TRUE)
```

In my situation, one dataset had the words under the 'word' column while another had the words under the 'term' column.